# Why does $A+$B and $A,$B interact differently with Test-Path

Tags: arrays, powershell, operators, pipeline

I have two arrays `$A` and `$B` both could potentially be empty.

```
$A = $B = @()
```

This works:

```
$A+$B | Test-Path
```

This does not work:

```
$A,$B | Test-Path
```

And returns the error:

> Test-Path : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is an empty array.

I would have expected both expressions to fail, as the `+` operator is adding one empty array to another, meaning the resulting array is still empty?

Looking at the overall types of both methods shows that they are the same type.

```
PS Y:\> $E = $A+$B
PS Y:\> $E.getType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     Object[]                                 System.Array

PS Y:\> $F = $A,$B
PS Y:\> $F.getType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     Object[]                                 System.Array
```

So why does `$A+$B` & `$A,$B` interact differently with `Test-Path`?

Comment: `$A + $B` concatenates the two empty arrays, creating one shallow empty array. `$A,$B` creates a new array containing two empty arrays

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$A+$B | ...` concatenates `$A` and `$B` before passing the resulting array to the pipeline. The pipeline then unrolls the (still empty) array, so you get `$null` and `Test-Path` is never called.

`$A,$B | ...` constructs an array with two nested arrays before passing it into the pipeline. The pipeline then unrolls the outer array and feeds each element (the empty arrays `$A` and `$B`) to `Test-Path`, thus causing the error you observed.

Basically you're doing `$A+$B → @()` in the former, and `$A,$B → @(@(), @())` in the latter case.